# It should show a message when i click on resend Invitation button

Tags: jquery, zend-framework

**This is my button**

```
<button id="resend-invitation-button-<?php echo $user['id'] ?>"
class="btn btn-warning cp_width_100pct resend-invitation-button height_36px"rel="<?php echo $user['email'] ?>"><?php echo $this->translate->_("invite_again") ?></button
```

**This is an info message**

```
<div id="user-invited-message-<?php echo $user['id']?>" class="alert alert-success org-user-messages" role="alert" style="display: none"><?php echo $this->translate->_("message_user_invited") ?></div>
```

**This is my ajax call**
     When I click on Invite Again button,  should show an info message like Invited Successfully**

```
$('.resend-invitation-button').click(function() {
    var email = $(this).attr('rel');
    var data = {
    email: email
    };
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax("/organization/users/resendinvite",{
    type: "POST",
    data: data       
    })
    .done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      if(response == 200) {
          $('.org-user-messages').hide();
          $('#user-invited-message-' + email).show();
          $('#orgstatus-span-' + userId).text("INVITED SUCCESSFULLY");
      }
      if(response == 404){
          $('.org-user-messages').hide();
      }
      if(response == 500){
          $('.org-user-messages').hide();
          $('#user-error-message-' + email).show();
      }
    })
    .fail(function(response) {
      console.log('FAILURE');
    });
});
```

Comment: Is it posible you can format your code, it's kinda hard to figure out what is what?

Comment: Ok i format it if it possibles

Comment: have you checked whether it is going in that `if` block, are you getting 200 success response from server or not. What kind of errors you are getting? Please be specific.

Comment: Sir i have fixed this issue

Comment: But still have another issue related to it

Comment: When i click on that button info message  displays but it displays with delay

Comment: It should display as soon as button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="the-return">

  [HTML is replaced when successful.]

</div>



<script type="text/javascript">

$("document").ready(function(){

  $(".js-ajax-php-json").click(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() `enter code here`+ "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "response.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html(
          "Favorite beverage: " + data["favorite_beverage"] + "<br />Favorite restaurant: " + data["favorite_restaurant"] + "<br />Gender: " + data["gender"] + "<br />JSON: " + data["json"]
        );
        alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I  checked with this code but it's not working, Please give me another solution.

Comment: Bhawna Sharma ,please check again my above replay  message or answer,

Comment: I have also fixed that  issue, But when i click on that button the info message display after a few seconds. User does not know the invitation has been sent or not?

Comment: So we should use spinner, can u help me ??

Comment: Or any othere solution for that ??

Comment: Yes you can used as spinner with hide and show property in jQuery with setTimeout function for you can hide spinner after send notification or show message

Comment: But how to use?

Comment: my jquery coding is wrriten above.. please try to tell me

Comment: How can i use spinner for that